# Filtering a List in Flutter using Riverpod and FutureProvider

Tags: flutter, hook, riverpod

i am learning Flutter and currently using Riverpod + Hooks as a State Management. Following several tutorials and articles i have succesfully retrieved data from an API and is showing correctly using a FutureProvider with .when clause

```
final caseEntries = ref.watch(caseEntriesFutureProvider);
  
//And the UI looks like this
  caseEntries.when(
                   data: (items) {
                    return GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(maxCrossAxisExtent: 380.0),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final item = items[index];
                        return CaseItem(item: item);
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    error: ((obj, error) => Text(error.toString())),
                    loading: (() => const material.CircularProgressIndicator()),
                  ),
```

Now, how can i filter the collection using a search term? Every tutorial i came across is either using a prepopulated List and filtering using an enum or doing some extra complicated stuff and not using a FutureProvider

EDIT: Added more sample code

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final caseEntries = ref.watch(caseEntriesFutureProvider);
    final searchTextController = useTextEditingController(text:"");

    useEffect(() {
      searchTextController.addListener(() {});
    }, [searchTextController]);
```

Comment: How do you want to filter the list? 
Do you want to filter the list by searching the item with the text field?

Comment: Yes, that would be the ideal approach, i already have my textfield with its controller using Hooks' useTextEditingController

Comment: What is the data type of `items` in the when method?
`List<What>` can you share what `What` is and what you want to search by in the class?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply

The data type is just a custom class called Case.. so a List<Case> the issue is not that of how to search and filtering using a property in the class, but. When the FutureProvider finishes loading the data, how can i filter that data and then notify the UI (in this case the .when widget) to rebuild